# .save() not inserting a data into collection without showing errors in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

.save function is not working without error its not inserting data into collection of a table. when i was inserting data into collection using mongodb command then data is inserting. I am also checking the mongoose connection it is working fine. when i am using else case in .save function then it will come in else condition but data is not inserting. model and routes code are bellow kindly help to resolve this issue.

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var User = require('../model/User');
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

    /* GET users listing. */
    router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('register', {title: 'User registrations page !'});
    });
    router.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
      res.render('login', {title: 'User Login page !'});
    });
    //Register process
    router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
        var name = req.body.fullname;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;


            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.name = name;
            newUser.email = email;
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = password;
            newUser.save(function(err, savedUser){
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).send();
              }
              return res.status(200).send();
            });
    });
 Creating a model user under the model folder which is including in users routes file 


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
var user = mongoose.model('myuser', userSchema);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userDet',{ useMongoClient: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Connection error');
    }
    // we're connected!
    else {
        console.log('We are connected !');
    }
  });
module.exports = user;
```

Comment: Please do not repeat the same line over and over again. It adds nothing of value.

Comment: sorry it was by mistake now its fine

Comment: What is the collection name your looking in. It should be inserting into collection by name `myusers`.

Comment: could you tell me in details because i am beginner

Comment: @NiteshSingh you want to post the data through routes. Am I right???

Comment: @NiteshSingh Did you tried to post data through POSTMAN? TO check whether your API is working properly???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NiteshSingh when you want to get the data from html form you need to do parsing. Make sure that your `html form` tag `action` must be same with `post route` `<form method="post" action="/register">`. Try this code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var User=require('../models/User');
var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

var userRouter = express.Router();
userRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

userRouter.post('/register',urlencodedParser,function(req, res, next){

 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 .then(item => {
 res.send("item saved to database");
 })
 .catch(err => {
 res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
 });
});

app.use('/register',userRouter);

module.exports = userRouter;
```

And you can follow this link https://medium.com/@ratracegrad/hitchhikers-guide-to-back-end-development-with-examples-3f97c70e0073
 Read this article from top to bottom. You will get an idea. Hope this helps...